# Proof by induction for a recursive sequence (closed form formula given)3

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was given:

> Show that the sequence defined by $b_k=b_{k-1}+2^k$ for $k\ge 2$, where $b_1 = 4$, is equivalently described by the closed formula $b_n = 2^{n+1}$.

I am not understanding where to even begin with this problem.  How do I prove this?

I started by inputting 1 into the closed formula to make sure it matches with b_1 = 4.

Comment: Do you know induction?

Comment: Acording to my notes, I have to Step 1: subsitute A(sub)1 into closed formula.  Check to be true.  Step 2: Substitues (m-1) into the closed formula.  Step 3: Substitue (m-1) closed formula into A(sub k REcursive formula for m

Comment: So did you try to follow these steps?

Comment: yeah, I came up with a simplified formula that looks like 2^m + 2^m

Comment: @BlaineMiller: That looks promising: $2^m + 2^m = 2\cdot 2^m = 2^{m+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $c_n=2^{n+1}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. You now have two sequences, $\langle b_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ and $\langle c_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$; the first is defined by the recurrence $b_n=b_{n-1}+2^n$ for $n\ge 2$, with initial condition $b_1=4$, and the second is defined by the formula $c_n=2^{n+1}$. The problem asks you to show that they are the same sequence, i.e., that $b_n=c_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

This is a statement about positive integers: for each positive integer $n$, $b_n=c_n$. Statements like that are often proved by induction. Moreover, the fact that each $b_n$ is defined in terms of the preceding one should remind you of the way a proof by induction works: you show that the statement about the number $n$ somehow implies the corresponding statement about the next number, $n+1$. Thus, you should try to prove this by induction.

- To get the induction started, is it true that $b_1=c_1$? That’s easy to check.
- For the induction step, you want assume as your induction hypothesis that $b_n=c_n$ for some $n\ge 1$ and prove from this that $b_{n+1}=c_{n+1}$. In other words, you’re assuming that $b_n=2^{n+1}$, and you want to prove from this that $b_{n+1}=2^{(n+1)+1}=2^{n+2}$. This is also straightforward; just use the recurrence defining $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_n$.

Comment: Okay, I think 'm sorta getting it, but wouldn't the closed formula have to equal the the simplified recursive formula? I don't know.  I'm just a little mixed up because we didn't plug anything in to simplify the recursive formula.

Comment: @Blaine: What do you mean by ‘the simplified recursive formula’?

Comment: hmmm...I think that I am meaning that if I substitute the closed formula into the recursive formula and simplify I cant prove it?  But by what you have said the two are equivalent if I put in any integer. You actually make more sense than my notes right now.

Comment: @Blaine: The recurrence describes a certain sequence, and the closed form describes a certain sequence; your task is to prove that those sequences are identical, which means precisely that for any $n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ are the same number. You’ll find if you actually carry out the induction step that the calculation does involve combining the recurrence with the closed form, but it’s not quite a matter of substituting the one into the other.